# Compiling a static executable

Tags: c, gcc, static-linking

I am trying to compile an statically-linked executable, but I cannot seem to avoid producing a dynamically-linked one instead.  I tried this compilation command first:

```
gcc -o test test.c -lcrypto -ldl -lz -static-libgcc
```

I have also tried just `-static` and `--disable-shared` with the same results.  I thought the above command would be enough to produce a static executable, but the `file` command tells me that the result is dynamically linked.

Can anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283021/compile-a-standalone-static-executable

Comment: Do you have static versions of libcrypto, libdl, and libz installed?

Comment: You should definitely use the `-static` flag in addition to `-static-libgcc`.  To the best of my knowledge, the latter does not imply static linking of libraries other than libgcc.

Comment: I figured out how to compile the executable to be statically linked.  The final command was "gcc Test.c  ~/openssl/libcrypto.a -lcrypto -ldl -lz -o Test --static -static-libgcc".  The final was close to what I had in the question.  I just needed to include the path to libcrypto.a.  I have marked the question as answered because my question was similar to another question with the exception that I have included OpenSSL.  Thanks.