# statically linked executable requires shared libraries

Tags: c++, static, embedded, shared-objects

EDIT: i asked a wrong question, don't reed, see clarification below.

I have cross compiled two archive files a.a and b.a and statically linked them to an executable exe.elf .
I have verified (following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15475134/6400297) instructions)weather my executable is indeed statically using readelf -dhl exe.elf:

```
user@host:~/program/bin$ readelf -dhl exe.elf
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - GNU
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x12a45
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          13513704 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000400, Version5 EABI, hard-float ABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         7
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         40
  Section header string table index: 39

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz Flg Align
  EXIDX          0x11c558 0x0012c558 0x0012c558 0x047a0 0x047a0 R   0x4
  LOAD           0x000000 0x00010000 0x00010000 0x120cfc 0x120cfc R E 0x10000
  LOAD           0x120f48 0x00140f48 0x00140f48 0x05ab8 0x0aa9c RW  0x10000
  NOTE           0x000114 0x00010114 0x00010114 0x00044 0x00044 R   0x4
  TLS            0x120f48 0x00140f48 0x00140f48 0x00038 0x000a0 R   0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000 RW  0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x120f48 0x00140f48 0x00140f48 0x040b8 0x040b8 R   0x1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .ARM.exidx
   01     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id .rel.dyn .init .iplt .text  __libc_freeres_fn __libc_thread_freeres_fn .fini .rodata __libc_subfreeres __libc_IO_vtables __libc_atexit __libc_thread_subfreeres .ARM.extab .ARM.exidx .eh_frame
   02     .tdata .init_array .fini_array .data.rel.ro .got .data .bss __libc_freeres_ptrs
   03     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id
   04     .tdata .tbss
   05
   06     .tdata .init_array .fini_array .data.rel.ro

There is no dynamic section in this file.
```

As this tells me, there is no dynamic section in this file.
    `nm | grep " U "`
spits out nothing checking for dynamic dependencies:

`ldd exe.elf
        not a dynamic executable`

also tells me this is a static executable.

When i transfer my program to my target computer (armv7) and try to execute it, it dares to tell me that i am missing shared objects.

```
user@target:/program/bin$ ./exe.elf
./exe.elf: error while loading shared libraries: libfirstlibrary.so: cannot 
open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

i dont have binutils on my target computer as this is a very minimal linux setup, which is part of the reason why i need to compile statically. My $LD_LIBRARY_PATH is empty, but i should not be needing it ... right?

I have compiled my apparently static executable exe.elf using the linaro toolchain with g++ -static -l:libfirstlib.a -l:libsecondlib.a as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20728782/6400297) post.
Can anybody help me clarify why my static library needs these shared objects? I will post further details if needed, i can't think of any more. Thanks.

EDIT:
Apparently i have accidentally copied the dynamically linked version of the program to the target without noticing it, ...twice... . Now that i transfered the actual static executable it works. I am very sorry.